# Bootstrap nav tabs span whole page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My goal here is to get the nav-tabs to span the whole page so the bottom line reaches the end of the page.  Additionally, I want the checkboxes to sit on top of this section to be in line with the tab links.  Here is my progress so far:

```
<div class="float-right">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input" />
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description">Show all</span>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description">
                Show some
            </span>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            <span class="custom-control-description">
                Show others
            </span>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Best</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jf7jp30g/

I've been messing around with trying to understand how to use z-index, but I don't seem to be making any progress there.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you written any CSS to try and solve this?

Comment: Yes, as I stated above, I had been messing around with z-index in trying to stack the elements in a manner that would allow the nav-tabs to extend across the whole screen.  I've tried many variations in tweaking the CSS, but I honestly can't think of a clean way to organize everything on here that would be of any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something along these lines?

https://jsfiddle.net/jf7jp30g/5/

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Next</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:auto;">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Best</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" style="padding-top:5px">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="custom-control-input" />
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">Show all</span>
      </label>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">
            Show some
        </span>
      </label>
      <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" />
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <span class="custom-control-description">
            Show others
        </span>
      </label>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is invalid HTML. You need to wrap the form in line item tags.

Comment: Thanks, was a little hasty with my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's still wrong. You need to wrap the form in a line item tag, not the individual parts inside of it. You can have pretty much whatever you want inside a `ul`, but those items have to be inside line item tags.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I am looking for, however, I am trying to get the checkboxes all the way to the far right side of the page.

Comment: See correction above.  Added `margin-right: auto` to the last `<li>` element before the form.  Also read up on navbars, they may help - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/

Comment: Ahh yes, perfect!  Thank you so much!  Apparently, I way over complicated this one.  Marked as accepted answer.